# Puppet- ERB template- Question about defined classes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, puppet

Puppet template files are erb rails files.

I want the line:

`Include modsecurity.d/*.conf`

To be included in the final file if the class mod_security is included.

From the puppet docs:
http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/templating.html -

> And this snippet will print all the
>   defined class in the catalog:

```
<% classes.each do |klass| -%>
The class <%= klass %> is defined
<% end -%>
```

Conditional:

```
<% if broadcast != "NONE" %>        broadcast <%= broadcast %> <% end %>
```

I am new to the syntax. Does defined mean the same as included? For the conditional how would I check a particular class i.e. if isdefined(mod_security)...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defined classes does mean that the class is included.  Just to be clear, the `<% if broadcast ...` bit is not the way to check the inclusion of the broadcast class, but rather to syntax of a conditional using the value of the broadcast variable, the classes array contains the names of all the defined classes.

This would be how you would check for the mod_security class for instance:

```
<% if classes.include?("mod_security") %>
conditional text
<% end %>
```

**Edit:**

Whoops...the method is called include? not includes?.  Fixed above.

Comment: I tried this and had no luck. It doesn't want to use the includes method. If I do `classes.inspect` it does appear to list the involved classes. Is there anyway I can check the list for a specific entry?

Comment: Josh -- I've updated my answer (added an "s" where it didn't belong), let me know it's still not working for you.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful doing this because whether the class is included in the 'classes' variable depends on *when* in the puppet run this particular template is evaluated, and that might be non-deterministic.  It's quite possible that your template will be evaluated and then later on during the run your mod_security class gets included and evaluated.

Two ways around this:

1. if you can guarantee it'll be added by an external node classifier, it's safe
2. better still, make a custom fact that ascertains the presence of mod_security and use that factname as your conditional variable.

   Facter.add("mod_security_version") do
      setcode do
          version = %{rpm -qa | grep mod_security}
          if version.empty?
                version = 0
          end
          version
       end
    end

Then in your template:

```
<% if ! mod_security_version.eql?("0") %>
Include modsecurity.d/*.conf
<% end %>
```

Note this needs to be a string comparison (not `mod_security_version != 0`) because all facter facts are strings once they hit ERB.